# PHP get content from external URL with GET parameters

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I copied this code from another question here on stack..

```
   $fbid = '666666666';
    $url = 'http://www.example.de/v/fffff.php'; // work
    $url = 'http://www.example.de/v/fffff.php?fbid=' . $fbid; // not working, page don't load

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache"
      ),
    ));

    $antwort = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
```

Anyone idea how to get the contents from url with GET parameters?

Comment: What happens when the parameter is added? What is the parameter value? `' $fbid` is invalid, is that your real code?

Comment: Excuse me, you are missing the concatenate part before `$fbid;` on the second line of your question (that part you say doesn't work), the point **.**. To be clear: all your second line should be this way `$url = 'http://www.example.de/v/fffff.php?fbid=' . $fbid;`

Comment: $fbid is also defined, I forgot to copy it too so that's not the issue

Comment: What are you getting on **$err** at the end or your code? What else message errors do you get? Have you check the developer panel of your browser?

Comment: I can't check what $err gives because the page don't load when I add GET stuff to the URL. Do it maybe have to be JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.` that concatenates `$fbid` to the url. And you need to instantiate the `curl` first as well. Change your code to:

```
        $fbid = 123;// as sample dbid
        $url = 'http://www.example.de/v/fffff.php'; // work
        $url = 'http://www.example.de/v/fffff.php?fbid='.$fbid; // not working, page don't load

        $curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
));

$antwort = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Hope this helps.